# Download blob videos urls

Tags: google-chrome

I want to download videos, but impossible with sites that i use as usual

link : https://www.tf1.fr/tf1/sept-a-huit/videos/sept-a-huit-life-du-dimanche-9-mai-2021-02981336.html

video downloader : https://www.videovor.com/fr/video-download-1

is there a dev who know how to fix this type of urls. i think content is blocked but maybe an experienced dev can help me to fix this because i really want to have methods to download this type of urls please,

many thanks

Answer (score 3):

For general downloading of videos in Chrome (for Linux, Mac, Windows+cygwin):

1. Enable request logging to a json file from `chrome://net-export/`
2. Visit the site and play the video in Chrome
3. Stop logging
4. Extract `.m3u8/.mp4` urls from the json file:
   `cat [json-file] | sed -n 's/.*"url":"\([^"]*\.m3u8\).*/- \1/p' | sort | uniq`
   `cat [json-file] | sed -n 's/.*"url":"\([^"]*\.mp4\).*/- \1/p' | sort | uniq`
5. Download url with `ffmpeg` (install if not on your system):
   `ffmpeg -i [url] -loglevel quiet -stats -c copy video.mp4`

*Note: This won't work if the site requires cookies to access the video url.*